# react.js how to rerender App.js when some action is fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple react.js with header and simple authorization, so if the user is logged in (user object is set in localstorage) - navbar shows, if not - navbar hides. THe code is as follows:

```
#App.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginPage from "./components/loginPage/loginPage";
import MainPage from "./components/dashboard/mainPage";
import AuditPage from "./components/auditPage/AuditPage.js";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Test01 from "./components/dev/test01";
import Test02 from "./components/dev/test02";
import {Router, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {history} from "./helpers/history";
import TestsNav from "./components/dev/TestsNav";


class App extends React.Component   {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <Router history={history}>
                {localStorage.getItem('user') && (//this fires only once, when the page is loaded
                    <Navbar history={history} />
                )}

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/audit" component={AuditPage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/test01" component={Test01}/>
                    <Route exact path="/test02" component={Test02}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export default connectedApp;
```

The problem is that when the user logs in and data is set to localstorage - navbar does not show - class App.js is not rerendered. I got a rendering condition for navbar - but it fires only once, when the page is loaded. So if I want navbar to show, I need to hit f5 and only after that it appears. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Try to implement Authenticated routes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do for this situation.

My Routes part:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
    {privateRoutes.map(({ path, component: Component }, idx) => (
        <PrivateRoute
        key={idx}
        exact
        path={path}
        component={() => (
            <SideNav>
              <Component />
            </SideNav>
        )}
        />
    ))}

    <IsAuthenticated exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

IsAuthenticated component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";


function IsAuthenticated({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.User.isLogin)
  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={props =>
        !isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default IsAuthenticated;
```

privateRoutes components:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.User.isLogin);
  return (
    <Route
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and my routes files contains something like this:

```
export const privateRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: HomePage
  },
];
```

I use redux for check if user is authenticated and check this in App.js when app start.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function from this component to login page. After login call the function (which will set a state and re-renders the component).

```
class App extends React.Component   {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this,state = {
      isAuthenticated: false
    }
  }

  setIsAuthenticated = (isAuthenticated) => this.setState({ isAuthenticated });
  render() {

    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <Router history={history}>
                {(this.state.isAuthenticated || localStorage.getItem('user')) && (//this fires only once, when the page is loaded
                    <Navbar history={history} />
                )}

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <LoginPage setIsAuthenticated={this.setIsAuthenticated} />}/>
// call props.setIsAuthenticated from login page after loginng in.
                    <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/audit" component={AuditPage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/test01" component={Test01}/>
                    <Route exact path="/test02" component={Test02}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export default connectedApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so easy. In App.js, call a function that says, `return App;`