# React Routing with Authentication and User Contexts

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to work out the best way of handling authentication and routing in my React application. I've used the methods outlined by [Kent Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications/) and [also here](https://kalm42.com/blog/how-to-handle-authentication-in-react-applications) by someone else expanding on his method.

Basically you have a context used to authenticate and one for the authenticated user info. If the user is authenticated then the `<AuthenticatedApp />` is rendered, if no user info present then the `<UnauthenticatedApp/>` is rendered.

The breakdown of the various providers is like:

```
AppContext.js

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <Router>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </Router>
);

export default AppProvider;
```

And my `App.js`,

```
function App() {
  const user = useUser();
  return user ? (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <AuthenticatedApp />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ) : (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <UnauthenticatedApp />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

How do I best handle routing between various components in both Unauthenticated and Authenticated components? Should I wrap them separately in `<Router>` or have `<Router` wrapping around at the top level above my contexts? I'm currently using the first method with react router at my top level above other context providers.

```
AuthenticatedApp.js

 const RedirectHome = () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;

const AuthenticatedApp = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <RedirectHome />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/dashboard">
      <DashboardNavbar />
      <Dashboard />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/projects">
      <DashboardNavbar />
      <Projects />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/*">
      <RedirectHome />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

```
UnauthenticatedApp.js

  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <LandingPage RightSide={UserLogin} />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/login">
      <LandingPage RightSide={UserLogin} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/signup">
      <LandingPage RightSide={UserSignup} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/*">
      <LandingPage RightSide={UserLogin} />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

Is this the best way of doing it? In order to logout I have the following:

```
AuthContext.js

 const history = useHistory();
  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('AUTH_TOKEN');
    refetch();
    history.push('/');
    history.go();
  };
```

Pushing the history to / changes the address but doesn't seem to change the page, it still sits on the Dashboard page and even with the removed JWT token I'm still not being provided with the `<Unauthenticated/>` component. I have to force a reload of the current page before the lack of JWT token on the authentication is noticed.

Sorry for the well of text, I'm just very confused!

Update #1

My useUser context/hook is:

```
const UserProvider = (props) => {
  const { data } = useAuth();

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    <UserContext.Provider value={data ? data.getWhoAmI : null} {...props} />
  );
};

const useUser = () => React.useContext(UserContext);

export { UserProvider, useUser };
```

And my AuthContext is:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const { loading, data, refetch } = useQuery(WHOAMI_QUERY);
  const [loginUser] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER_MUTATION);
  const [signupUser] = useMutation(SIGNUP_USER_MUTATION);

  const signin = async (username, password) =>
    loginUser({ variables: { username, password } }).then((res) => {
      if (res && res.data && res.data.loginUser && res.data.loginUser.token) {
        const { token } = res.data.loginUser;
        localStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', token);
        refetch();
      } else {
        throw Error('No token returned');
      }
      return res;
    });

  const signup = (firstName, lastName, username, email, password) =>
    signupUser({
      variables: { firstName, lastName, username, email, password },
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res && res.data && res.data.signup && res.data.signup.token) {
        const { token } = res.data.signup;
        localStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', token);
        refetch();
      } else {
        throw Error('No token returned');
      }
      return res;
    });

  const history = useHistory();
  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('AUTH_TOKEN');
    refetch();
    history.push('/');
    history.go();
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading!</p>;
  }
  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ data, signin, signup, logout }} {...props} />
  );
};

const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

Comment: At first glance there is nothing glaringly wrong here.  Your structure with one `Router` and two `Switch` blocks seems like it should be fine.  So I'm not sure where the error is.

Comment: If we are redirecting from "/login" to "/" that seems like it would work.  Are we redirecting from "/" (where logged out) to "/" (where logged in)?  It's possible that might not trigger a refresh because the path is the same.

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. I would have thought pushing the history change would be enough, but if all it takes is to reload the page following the token removal and history.push then maybe it's an acceptable solution? Just feels clunky.

Comment: I've updated the AuthenticatedApp to show the Redirect. When logged in, "/" redirects to "/dashboard". So if I'm on /dashboard and click logout, the JWT token is deleted then history.push("/") is called, which should then result in me being redirected back to "/dashboard" but without the user / JWT stored so the UnauthenticatedApp component should be rendered taking me back to the login page.

Comment: `history.push("/")` would redirect them to the URL `"/"`, no?

Comment: It would, which is then redirecting to /dashboard. I've got the code in the post, AuthenticatedApp.js.

Comment: You can include a `state` as a second argument in `history.push`.  Not sure if that helps.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/navigation.md  Another idea is to conditionally render a `Redirect` component (which uses `history` behind the scenes).  If there were only one possible logged out page I would redirect all logged out traffic in `AuthProvider` but you have two (sign up and log in) so it becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no state change in your App.js file, so it is not being re-rendered after your user logs out. You would have to use the useEffect hook or switch to a class-based component to include state.

The bottom-most code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849807/react-js-how-to-rerender-app-js-when-some-action-is-fired) shows how they do it by passing the login function down through props to set the state in App.js. Your logout function could work similarly. I've done something similar on my site.

Comment: I would assume that `useUser` is a stateful hook.  If the `user` returned from `const user = useUser();` changes, that would cause `App` to re-render and presumably switch from `AuthenticatedApp` to `UnauthenticatedApp `.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give that a try. Any benefits to doing it that way and not doing it the way I outlined above?

Comment: I've posted the code of useUser and my AuthContext file.

Comment: Does logout change the value of { data } that you're retrieving in your AuthContext?

Comment: My understanding is that it should. I've added my AuthContext code at the bottom of the post. { data } is the response from querying my API for the user that matches the ID contained within the JWT, which is deleted on logout. Logout deletes the token and calls refetch() which should then update {data} with the new response.

Comment: I've put a console.log(data) when App is rendered, it's not being rendered when I click logout, and inspecting the AuthProvider Context.Provider in devtools seems to show data still containing the user info.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking deeper into the GraphQL query getWhoAmI, it seems that when I logout which calls refetch() on the getWhoAmI query it's unable to use the JWT to authenticate the request and find the user and which then does`throw new AuthenticationError('You do not have permission for this request');` which does not update { data }, but oddly does not return an {error} either.

If I change the GraphQL resolver to return null instead of the error, I'm then logged out as { data } changes from the user info to null which causes a re-render.